# In regular expression, how match two diferent cases of string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get strings from a list of files with ls command. I have this two cases:

```
"filename"
"link File" -> "filename"
```

In python, I did this code:

```
print(re.findall( r'"(.*?)"', linha))
```

The RE i did:

```
"(.*?)"               -: match ['filename']                CORRECT
                               ['link File" -> "filename'] WRONG
"(.*?)" -> "(.*?)"    -: match ['']                        WRONG
                               ['link File', 'filename']   CORRECT
```

What is the RE to get this result in the same RE:

```
                      -: match ['filename', '']            CORRECT
                               ['link File', 'filename']   CORRECT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an optional section, so use a `?` to match it if it is there. Next, you want to exclude `"` from your matches, since your targets are surrounded by quotes. This makes it easier for the regex engine to match your string:

```
"([^"]*)"(?: -> "([^"]*)")?
```

The `(?:...)` grouping is non-capturing, the `?` after it makes it optional.

When you use this with `re.findall()`, you'll always get tuples with two groups, the second one being empty for those inputs where `-> "..."` is missing:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"(?: -> "([^"]*)")?', '"filename"')
[('filename', '')]
>>> re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"(?: -> "([^"]*)")?', '"link File" -> "filename"')
[('link File', 'filename')]
```

I've created [an online demonstration with Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bQbm5T/1) (which, for some reason, requires us to explicitly escape double quotes, not something that Python actually would require). It contains a breakdown of the pattern on the right-hand side under the 'Explanation' banner.

Comment: great.. I was trying to use the | (OR) operator. First, very good idea the `[^"]` to not get the other " in second case. And the `(?:...)` and the `?` expression was I need in this case.